# How to delete the space between the beginning of the cell and the text?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I Have a table view with cells that only contains text, how can I remove or reduce the space between the beginning of the cell and the text?

The space in red is the one that I want to delete:

[image]

Comment: have you tried with setting layourMargin of tableView & cell to zero ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use auto layout, all you need to do is to add constraints to make padding left to be 0, or whatever padding you need, in the same way

[image]

Comment: And how can I do this with the default textLabel that the cell have?

Comment: @dmram You will have to create the custom cell